# How to use chrome.sockets.tcp.connect via https? if not, any other way?

Tags: sockets, tcp, google-chrome-app

When I use this method in chrome 38,it output:

```
Unchecked runtime.lastError while running sockets.tcp.secure: net::ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
    at Object.callback (chrome-extension://dljefdleijndedodoomhhlajcjddenpf/main.js:66:32)
```

This is my code:

```
chrome.sockets.tcp.create({}, function (createInfo) {
    var socketId = createInfo.socketId;
    chrome.sockets.tcp.connect(socketId, 'www.alipay.com', 443, function (connectResult) {
        if (connectResult !== 0) {
          return;
        } 
        chrome.sockets.tcp.secure(socketId,{tlsVersion:{min:"ssl3",max:"tls1.2"}},function(secureResult) {
            console.log("secureResult",secureResult);
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to follow https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=403076 ("Unable to use new chrome.sockets.tcp.secure API due to setPause not taking immediate effect"), which sounds similar to your issue. If it is, then please star the bug and wait for a resolution.